# How to generate a strong electromagnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I'm working on a project and I need help generating a strong magnetic field over an air gap with the lowest material weight that could be achieved.  I have tried to use permanent magnets but its not effective so I need to know the best way to generate a strong fixed electromagnetic field with the lightest material.

The attached image is a simple drawing shows the direction I need to generate the field in the boxes are the field source:
$\hspace{150px}$[image].

Comment: Neodymium permanent magnets aren't strong enough?

Comment: I think he's looking for strong field AND low weight -- im guessing the magnets are too heavy...

Comment: Exactly the magnets are very heavy to my project compared to the field i need ..

Answer (score 2):

How many teslas?  Uniform field?  For how long?  Z-pinch in a flash, or an exploded Helmholtz pair.  For a sustained field, pre-formed coils of niobium stannide superconductor cooled to 4 kelvins (liquid helium) or below (pumped liquid helium superfluid) in a Halbach array,
[image]

If you have a liquid nitrogen budget, yttrium barium copper oxide (YBa2Cu3O7-x).

http://www.ndfeb-info.com/neodymium_grades.aspx 
Are you certain that N52 Fe-Nd-B won't do it?  As a Halbach array?  That's good for more than a tesla in the gap, 
http://www.kjmagnetics.com/proddetail.asp?prod=ay0x030-c

Comment: I dont have a budget for a liquid nitrogen beside using it is gonna kill the idea of low weight .. maybe if my project worked using the liquid nitrogen and superconductors might be more efficient but not on a prototype.. i dont need the field fixed over a point as i showed on my graph i need it between to plates uniform at a large distance as i showed. the permanent magnets r perfect but they are just heave and weaker than i need

Answer (score 1):

The magnitude of electric field at a point due to an infinite plane sheet of uniform charge density is independent of its distance from the sheet.

Mathematically, from gauss law magnitude of electric field at a point due to an plane charged sheet is given by the following equation: 
$$E=\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}$$
where $\sigma$ is surface charge density, $\epsilon_0$ is the absolute permittivity of the free space.

As you are asking for the strong electromagnetic field, for the electric field I would suggest you to use plane sheet of uniform charge density, as you increase the charge density, field will increase. The advantage is that intensity of electric field will not reduce even at large distance from the sheet. I don't know how you would manage to have such sheet, but little approximated one would help.

[image]

For magnetic field, you can't have a plane sheet as you had for the purpose of electric field, the reason is magnetic monopole don't exist. For the magnetic field you can make a solenoid with its axis in the region where you want field.

Comment: i thought about using two solenoids in both direction to sustain the magnetic field in the area i need its just the diameter has to be small and i need my field on a plate like my graph .. u think i can make a rectangular solenoid ? i dont know if that is gonna work if u have an idea about that can u please explain ??